# How to prove the existence of continous functions who approximates Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove the Lebesgue Riemann lemma but before I need to prove this:

Let be $\left(\mathbb{R},A^*_{\mathbb{R}},\overline{\lambda}\right)$ the measurable Lebesgue space of $\mathbb{R},$ $p\in[1,\infty), \epsilon>0$ and $|f|^p$ integrable. Then exists $A>0$ and a continuous function $g$ s.t. $g(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-A,A])\subseteq\{0\}$ and $\int|f-g|^p d\overline{\lambda}<\epsilon.$

Comment: How do you define Lebesgue-integrable functions? In some courses the underlieing space of "good functions" is already a space of continuous functions.

Comment: In measure theory at the beginning you define the integral for non negative simple functions, and then you define for any non negative measurable function, both integrals can be infinite so you say that a function is integrable if the integral is finite.

Comment: f doesn't need to be continous, just a measurable function.

Comment: So you want to prove that $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb R)$? This should be in almost any analysis text. Here is a [sketch](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140952/using-lusins-theorem-to-show-that-continuous-functions-are-dense-in-lp)

Comment: Ok, then how do you define measurable functions?